# enable ng-show value as true in protractor

Tags: angularjs, protractor

In spec.js ,where i wrote protractor test for signup with fullname,email and contact number.If user signed up successfully then ng-show value will be true and div will be shown with signup success message.

signup.html div to show success message :

```
 <div class="form-success-forgot" ng-show="isSignedUp">
            <h5>
                <strong><span ng-bind="signedUpSuccessMessage"></span></strong>
            </h5>
        </div>
```

Spec.js

```
 describe('Test signup ', function() {
            var fullname=element(by.model('fullName'));
            var email= element(by.model('email'));
            var cntNo= element(by.model('contactNo'));
            var signup= element(by.css("button[type='submit']"));
            var isSignup=element(by.css('.form-success-forgot'));
                beforeEach(function() {

            });
            it('signup success', function() {
             browser.get('http://localhost/signup');
            fullname.sendKeys('test user');
            email.sendKeys('testuser_01@yopmail.com');
            cntNo.sendKeys('123-456-7890');
            expect(isSignup.isEnabled()).toBe(true);
            signup.click();
            expect(isSignup.isEnabled()).toBe(false);
                element(by.binding('signedUpSuccessMessage')).sendKeys('Thanks for signing up');
                //element(by.css("form-success-forgot")).sendKeys(true);
             });
             });
```

But getting error stack as

```
Message:
    Expected true to be false.
  Stack:
    Error: Failed expectation
        at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\example\example_spec.js:20:31)
        at C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_mod
ules\jasminewd2\index.js:112:25
        at new ManagedPromise (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:1067:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_module
s\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2396:12)
        at schedulerExecute (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\p
rotractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:95:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules
\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2970:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mod
ules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2953:27)
        at asyncRun (C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protracto
r\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:2860:25)
        at C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_mod
ules\selenium-webdriver\lib\promise.js:676:7
  Message:
    Failed: element not visible
      (Session info: chrome=58.0.3029.110)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc5679
15b233),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)
```

How to enable or set true for ng-show value to make the div element visible ?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see in the code you are using the wrong check. [isEnabled](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isEnabled) is only for checking if an `input` is enabled, as dicted by the disabled attribute.

What I think you need is [isDisplayed](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.isDisplayed) or [isPresent](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.isPresent).

Be aware of the difference that `isPresent()` checks if the element is present in the DOM (not if it is displayed) and `isDisplayed()` checks if the element is **present in the DOM AND visible** on the page.

Hope this helps

Comment: Is there a css animation on the button? What if you do a `browser.sleep(3000)`, just to check

Comment: Even `isDisplayed()` not working. Getting the same error.

Comment: Nope @wswebcreation

Comment: Do you have an example project with your setup and site you want to test?